# Baffled by results of the render command in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say you have a post with comments on the same page, and you render a form for capturing a new comment also on the same page as you are displaying the post/comments. A post `has_many` comments. Code as follows:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

...

  def show
    @post = Post.find(:params[id])
    @comment = Post.comments.new
  end
...

end
```

Now when you call `<%= @post.comments.count %>` in your views it gives the number of comments that have been saved, but if you call `<%= render @post.comments %>` it returns all the saved comments PLUS the newly created (but not yet saved and therefore still invalid) comment. Why is this? This has really taken me time to find this and I can't imagine that this would be useful, why not just render all the valid database records?

Has anyone else ran into this? Easy to fix but puzzling..

Answer (score 0):

Well, @post.comments.count actually does a database query and can therefore only return the number of saved records. (Use @post.comments.size or .length) for the number of objects in your collection.

The render call, AFAIK, only loops over the objects in the collection.

The thing to know here is the difference between when you do actual queries with the association, and when active record is using the cached objects. It is perhaps easy to assume that the comments in @post.comments is just an Array. It actually is a fancy proxy object that, depending on method called and state of the cached collection, acts like an Array or as an interface to the Model's query methods.

Comment: Ok, but I presume a query has to be done when I do @post.comments as well? My thinking is that since I have not assigned the array of comments to an instance variable, only the post object, this must be retrieved from the database.

Comment: Well, it has to be done at some point, of course. AR usually lazy-loads association objects the first time they are actually used, and afterwards only reloads the cache if you do something to change the collection (or do an explicit find or something). I'm not 100% sure, but the comments.new call might already load the other comments, and remember an unsaved object at the end.